# Extracting a Json Object using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a Collection if I try

```
$plan=Plan::where('id',15)->first() I get

    App\Plan {#3974
     id: 15,
     title: "{"en":"title eng","ar":"gf"}",
     sub_title: "{"en":"sub title eng","ar":"gfh"}",
     description: "{"en":"des eng","ar":"g"}",
     created_at: "2022-03-17 15:54:59",
     updated_at: "2022-03-17 15:54:59",}
```

I'm trying to get the title as it is to pass it but whenever I try

```
$plan['title']
```

I only get title eng I'm expecting to get {"en":"title eng","ar":"gf"}
I tried json_decode it returned null

Comment: You don't appear to have an _array_ there, but an instance of `App\Plan`. So use object property access syntax, if those properties are public, and else, go look for what getter methods are available.

Comment: @CBroe [] or -> are valid in a collection furthermore $plan->title also returns 'title eng'

Comment: Then there's probably some "magic" involved there, that automatically picks the value out of the structure, that corresponds to the current language.

Comment: It looks like it's automatically translating the properties, so if your language is set to English, then `$plan['title']` will show `title eng`, while if your language was set to AR, then it would show `gf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to have a getter that returns the correct title, in order to get the raw, original attribute you'll need to use the `getAttributes` method.

```php
$plan->getAttributes()['title'];
```